# How to create missing folders from path with PrintWriter?

Tags: java, eclipse, outputstream, fileoutputstream, printwriter

I'm writing a string file from disk using `PrintWriter` with this code:

```
public static void storeString(String string, String path) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");       
        out.println(string);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the path contains a directory then PrintWriter throws an exception. How can I tell PrintWriter to create missing folders of its path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PrintWriter` constructor that takes a `File`:

```
PrintWriter(File file)
```

and the file might be created using the following code:

```
File fullPath = new File(path);
File directory = new File(fullPath.getParent());
directory.mkdirs();
File file = new File(directory, fullPath.getName());
```

Comment: @NullPointerException I have updated the answer. Now it uses `path`. It is not a problem if the dir already exists.

Comment: should do exist() first?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        storeString("salam", "/yourPath/someUncreatedDir/yourfile.txt");
    }

    public static void storeString(String string, String path) {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            File dir = new File((new File(path)).getParent());
            dir.mkdirs();
            out = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
            out.println(string);
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```